# What is the best way to organize HTML file Resources in WPF?

Tags: html, wpf, visual-studio, resources

Currently I have my HTML files marked as Content Resources.
I load them into my WebBrowser WPF control, this works fine.

This is, because I think it is not possible to hold them as resources in the executable (which I would like to do) because relative paths in the HTML file cannot be resolved (e.g. css or scripts).

Is this the only way or am I missing something?

I have the following ideas:

1) I save all the resource into a temporary folder and load them from there

2) I use a callback event (if there is one) when the control tries to load the referenced css/script files to load the file from the resources.